# How to load data and return promise?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model class:

```
export class Model {
  constructor(public model: any, public repository: RepositoryService) {
  }

   public hasChildren(id: number) {
        return this.model.childs && this.model.findIndex((opt) => opt.id == id) == -1;
    }

    public getChildren(id: number): Promise<any> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.hasChildren(id)) {
            resolve(this.model.childs);
        } else {
          this.repository.loadChildren().subscribe((response) => {
            resolve(response);
          })
        }
      });
    }
}
```

// Create instance

```
this.model = new Model(dataModel, this.repositoryService);
```

I try to get data or load if there is not in model:

```
this.model.getChildren(value).then((data) => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

My problem is in `public getChildren(id: number): Promise<any> {}` method. How to use promise here correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you have to create a Promise object (due to the fact you aren't rejecting it in any case), try to use async/await syntax in this way:

```
async public getChildren(id: number): Promise<any> {
    if (this.hasChildren(id))
       return (this.model.childs)
    return (await this.repository.loadChildren().toPromise())
}
```